# How to Redirect to a URL in PHP from with Post Data as URL String

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have searched a lot but did not find any answer...

My Question is, let's say I have a random page and user click on the download button to download a file, and the html in the button is:

```
<form action="http://seconddomain.com/thanks-for-downloading/" target="_blank" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="FileID" value="dYnte-m9bZ4"> 
    <div align="center">
        <input alt="Download Movie" src="image url here" type="image">   
    </div>
</form>
```

This data is submitted to the next page with post method using in the form, as you can note the value is defined as "dYnte-m9bZ4"
In this case, this value is the file download link, eg: downlaodfile.com/dYnte-m9bZ4

I want that when this data is submitted with post method on the next page there should be some PHP code that will automatically attach the defined value to the server URL/link as downlaodfile.com/dYnte-m9bZ4 and the user will be automatically redirected to the download page.

If this is not possible with post form method, then please suggest any other method...

Please tell me how can I do it.
Thanks...

Comment: To download a file, I think you need FTP (File Transfer Protocol)

Comment: @Duryab I tried to show you the skeleton of best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line,from where you want to redirect in your post handler php file.

```
 $var = $_POST["FileID"];

 // do input validation ,type-check etc on $var. 

 header("Location: http://downlaodfile.com/".$var);
```

I have done same thing of redirecting after form submission 
you can check my code @ [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/pintulalm/jefto/src/093a37f24eadccf694840ccae241917e7da2af4a/in_ctrl.php?at=release&fileviewer=file-view-default) line no 459 of link

Comment: Aww, Thank you very much <3
It just worked for me, thanks a lot dear.. :)

Comment: Great, I have also checked your code, and got everything, thank you very much :)

Comment: Well ,You are  welcome, I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: And dude how can I tell the user if the FileID is empty, by showing a message like "No file to download"

Comment: You can do this in many ways . check if FileID is null? using php string function .

Comment: Can you please write the full method in answer, I don't know this full method using using php string function etc... Thanks...

Comment: You can do this in many ways . check if FileID is null? using php function like line below 400 else part does in my given link.  or  do JavaScript check before form submit .  javascript code ,you need to incude jquery for it `$(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();
          alert("Nothing to download or whatever your message ");
        });

Comment: Here is php code ,if(empty($_POST["FileID"])){

//do your submission work here 

}
else
{
//do error handling code here 
}

Comment: @PintuLalM That is the gist of things. Remember though, the `FileID` is user input and should be handled accordingly.

Comment: Very insecure way of doing this.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge , Thanks , but developer has to handle intermediate security ,input validation ,etc.

Answer (score 0):

Never use user input directly. Never.
Sanitize and validate before using user input.
Escape data when necessary (when data switches execution contexts).

```
Note: This does not include error handling. This is just a skeleton.

$filteredPost  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filterRulesArray);   //Sanitize

$validatedPost = filter_var_array($filterdPost, $validationRulesArray)  //Validate

$fileId = urlencode($validatedPost['FileID']);  //Potentially, an important step in this case.

header("Location: http://downloadfile.com/{$fileId}");
```

PHP Manual: [filter_input_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php)

PHP Manual: [filter_var_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php)

PHP Manual: [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)